# My application is not launched in Android Emulator

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I am new to the development of mobile applications with Android.
The Kotlin application once built, does not appear in the android-studio emulator (Pixel XL API 30: Android 11.0 (Google API))

ADB is unable to debug the application:

```
$ adb shell am start -n "paris.ksainthi.soundpark/paris.ksainthi.soundpark.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Timed out waiting for process (paris.ksainthi.soundpark) to appear on Pixel_XL_API_30 [emulator-5554].
```

The application is present in the list of applications in the configuration. But it is not on the home, nor launched.
Here is my build.gradle file:

```
    plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    buildToolsVersion '30.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "paris.ksainthi.soundpark"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0-alpha02'
}
```

Here is the configuration of my application:

Deploy: Default APK
Launch: Specified Activity, paris.ksainthi.soundpark.MainActivity

Comment: Have you tried deleting the created emulator in the Android Virtual Device Manager window and recreating it again?

Comment: @FlashspeedIfe yes.. Same error.